# Enumeration of the keys in a SharedPreference

Tags: android

Hoi

I try to create an highscore list using SharedPreferences however I would like to enumerate the keys or query how many keys there are? The idea is to have at the max a list of eight value pairs, however this starts at zero. By enumerating the keys (usernames) I can use the keys to load the values.

Thanks in advance
Jasper de Keijzer

Answer (score 3):

Call `getAll().keySet()` to get a `Set` of the keys.